# OpenCL Linking Error for AMD SDK on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opencl

I have managed to install the Intel and the AMD OpenCL SDKs on Ubuntu 13.10, but when linking I am getting the following:

```
...    
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:4555: undefined reference to `clSetKernelArg'
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:4555: undefined reference to `clSetKernelArg'
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:4555: undefined reference to `clSetKernelArg'
./obj/main.o: In function `setArg<float>':
...
```

And the list goes on. The compiler flags I am using are:

```
CFLAGS      = -O3 -Wno-write-strings -g -pthread -I/opt/AMDAPP/include
LFLAGS     = -L /opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/
```

Furthermore, the linker does not recognize the -lOpenCL flag. Could it be a faulty installation? If so, how can it be fixed?

EDIT:

The same happends for the following flags:

```
CFLAGS      = -O3 -Wno-write-strings -g -pthread -I  /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-3.1.1.11385/include
LFLAGS     = -L /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-3.1.1.11385/lib64
```

With the compile/link commands:

```
TARGET          = mgsolve
OBJ             = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp))

$(TARGET): $(BUILD_DIR) $(OBJ)
    @echo "===>  LINKING  $@"
    $(Q)$(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(LFLAGS)
```

--Daniel

Comment: you are not providing the name of the library, it's the lack of the `-l` flag

Comment: that did the trick! Pretty obvious once you look at it..